# What is the algebraic group whose $\mathbb Q_p$-rational points are the group $\mathrm{GU}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, linear-groups, galois-representations, reductive-groups

For any field $K$, I denote by $\Gamma_K = \mathrm{Gal}(\overline K/K)$ its absolute Galois group. Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\mathbb Q_{p^2}$ denote a quadratic unramified extension of the field $\mathbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers. Let $\sigma_0$ be the non-trivial element of the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q_{p^2}/\mathbb Q_{p})$. Let $n$ be a positive integer, and define on the vector space $\mathbb Q_{p^2}^{n}$ the $\sigma$-hermitian form which, in the canonical basis, is represented by the following matrix
$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
& & & & 1\\
& & & -1 & \\
& & 1 & & \\
& \unicode{x22F0} & & & \\
(-1)^{n-1} & & & &
\end{bmatrix}$$
With such data, one can first define the associated unitary group denoted by $\mathrm U_n(\mathbb Q_p)$. It is the group consisting of all $\mathbb Q_{p^2}$-linear automorphisms of $\mathbb Q_{p^2}^n$ which preserve the hermitian form above. We can put it into a geometrico-algebraic setting, by recognizing that $U_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is no other than the group of $\mathbb Q_p$-rational points of the algebraic (reductive) group $\mathbb G = \mathrm{GL}_n$ over $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$, equipped with the following action of the absolute Galois group $\Gamma = \Gamma_{\mathbb Q_p}$ :
$$\forall \sigma \in \Gamma, \forall g \in \mathbb G, \quad\quad \sigma\cdot g := 
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
\sigma(g) & \text{ if } & g \in \Gamma_{\mathbb Q_{p^2}}\\
J\sigma(g)^{-T}J^{-1} & \text{ if } & g \in \Gamma\setminus \Gamma_{\mathbb Q_{p^2}}
\end{matrix} \right.$$
where $\sigma(g)$ is the matrix $g$ with $\sigma$ applied to all its coefficients, and where $g^{-T}$ is the inverse of the transpose of $g$.
In essence, it means that we have a natural identification (equality)
$$\mathrm U_n(\mathbb Q_p) \simeq \mathbb G(\mathbb Q_p) = \mathbb G(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})^{\Gamma} = \mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb Q_p})^{\Gamma}$$
In the terminology of classical groups, I think that $\mathrm U_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ is called the $p$-adic quasi-split unitary group of dimension $n$. It's nothing but $\mathrm{GL}_n$ with a twisted $\mathbb Q_p$-structure.

Now, what if I want to replace the unitary group with the group of unitary similitudes $\mathrm{GU}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$ ? This is defined as the group of $\mathbb Q_{p^2}$-linear automorphisms of $\mathbb Q_{p^2}^{n}$ which preserve the hermitian form *up to some unit scalar in* $\mathbb Q_{p}^{\times}$. In a similar fashion as above, I would like to find a reductive group $\mathbb H$ over $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$ with some Galois action, so that its group of $\mathbb Q_p$-rational points is naturally $\mathrm{GU}_n(\mathbb Q_p)$. Of course, just $\mathrm{GL}_n$ won't do as we need to keep track of the unit scalar somehow. Could $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathbb G_m$ do the work instead ?

Comment: Preserving things up to scalar is the same as preserving them on the nose in the *projective space*. Maybe you should start from $\mathbb{P}GL_n$?

Comment: I'll add here, for sake of completeness, that the matrix $J$ I use above isn't the correct one as pointed out in the answer too. I should take $J$ with only $1$ on the antidiagonal. The version with alternating $1$ and $-1$ becomes relevant when one considers the $L$-group, as explained in the notes linked in the answer.

Comment: @Suzet I didn't realize you were going to delete your other question about GU(2), so I can't follow up there.  Anyway, GU(2) is essentially an extension of a quaternion algebra.  E.g., see the beginning of Shimura's 1964 Annals paper, which is also relevant for this question.

Comment: @Kimball Sorry for the confusion and thanks a lot for reaching up to this question ; this reference is pretty enlightening. I deleted the previous question following your remark, as I did not want any other Mathstack user to be fooled by my wrong arguments... which I was quite ashamed, I should have realized it earlier ! I will start thinking about it from the start again, and if I encounter any problem I'll make a new question here. Thank you again =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. Let $J$ be a hermitian matrix (yours is only if $n$ is odd) and write $K=\mathbb{Q}_{p^2}$. Then in fact
$$GU_K\cong GL_{n,K}\times \mathbb{G}_{m,K} $$
and we have the short exact sequence
$$1\to GL_{n,K}\to GL_{n,K}\times \mathbb{G}_{m,K}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,K}\to 1$$
which is the base change to $K$ of the short exact sequence (over $\mathbb{Q}_p$)
$$1\to U\to GU\to \mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{Q}_p}\to 1.$$
The above isomorphism is given as follows: Let $R$ be a $K$-algebra, then $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} K\cong R\oplus R$ and thus
$$ GU(R)=\{(g,h)\in GL_n(R\oplus R)\mid (g,h)(J,J^t)(h^t,g^t)=\lambda\cdot(J,J^t)\}.$$
Writing out these conditions, it means you need
$$ gJh^t=\lambda\cdot J$$
and
$$ hJ^tg^t=\lambda\cdot J^t.$$
But then you can choose any $g\in GL_n(R)$ and set $h=\lambda J^tg^{-t}J^{-t}$ .
You can see [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/maths/research/notes/what_does_a_general_unitary_group_look_like.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about the notes that you linked ; they are quite useful for sorting things out !